# Finding the limit of the average of a sequence?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, code-request, code-review, coding-style

[image]

```
 Clear["Global`*"]
 G[s_] := Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Select[Flatten[Table[1/Round[(2^s)/m], {m, 1, 2^s}]],Between[#, {0, 1}] &]]]          
 f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Log[1/x], PrimeQ[1/x]}}, x]
 Averagef[s_] := Averagef[s] = N[Mean[Table[Simplify[f[G[s][[x]]]], {x, 1, Length[G[s]]}]]]
```

I want to find values of `Averagef[s_]` for larger values of `s`.

The problem is I'm unable to calculate `Averagef[s_]` past `s=16`

How do we improve my code to calculate `Averagef[s_]` for larger values of `s`? Does the limit of `Averagef[s_]` exist as `s` approaches infinity?

Comment: It might be easier if you define $f$ in terms of $m$ instead of $x = 1/m$. But it looks hard, because I'm not sure whether *Mathematica* can analyze (mathematically) the condition in the definition of $f$ — maybe there's someone here or at WRI who knows. You might have to do some of the mathematics yourself.

Comment: Are you missing a `Mean` in the definition of `Averagef`, or is it supposed to return a list of varying length?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oops. Fixed it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 What does WRI stand for?

Comment: Wolfram Research Inc., the maker of Mathematica.